# How should file names be formatted?

Tags: discussion, formatting

Many posts contain files' names and also the code contained in them. Usually I have found the file names formatted as code (`my_file.py`), in bold (**my_file.py**) or without format at all.

What's the formal way to format the file names?

Comment: I prefer italics for _filenames_.

Comment: Duplicate on Meta.SE: [Which markdown should be used for filename of code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246900)

Comment: Please, don't use bold. It draws too much attention when the file name usually is not that important. Use bold for important things instead.

Comment: Just be happy it's included... :) I don't care how it's formatted, I'm way more concerned with whether I can understand the question and if the asker has put any effort into solving their own problem. IMO: it's not code so don't format it that way... it's not that important so don't bold it (plus it's distracting) and italics is for emphasis. I prefer to see it just as plain text. It should be clear to those involved that it's a file name all by itself.

Comment: File names can be long and contain dots that might be confused with punctuation, and spaces, as sometimes happens in MS Windows. (Whole file paths can even contain slashes and colons.) Inline code style can prevent the such file names from blending in with surrounding sentence and thereby ruining it. For example: This is a sentence containing a file named `oh this name has spaces.and.dots` which may be hard to read without the file in inline code style. Italics or bold don't solve the problem well since they don't "bind" the parts of the file name as closely as the code style box.

Comment: It would be nice to find a thorough discussion of this *in the context of Markdown in general* rather than simply for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JeffC it's not always clear that's a file name because it may contain spaces, dots and other words/punctuations. With a clear format it'll be much more readable

Comment: @phuclv for files with spacing double quoting is appropriate - just as one would do in a terminal. No need for extra emphasis

Comment: @phuclv You are responding to a comment from 7 years ago... that said, if the filename contains spaces, etc. that you think might confuse a reader, you can easily enclose the entire file name in double quotes... it's still clear with no extra (incorrect) formatting needed.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no formal answer in the [formatting section of help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for this. Thus at least I feel that the correct way to do it isn't about the format used but rather about consistence within the post. Also another point to be taken into consideration is the readability that can be improved greatly by differing between `code blocks` and *file names* if both are regularly used in the code.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the post's context. Still, personally I would not use italics for technical-relevant parts of my postings. I tend to use italics to indicate _non-formal_ or sloppy parts, especially because I'm no native speaker.

Comment: What about writing them in bold? is that also OK?

Comment: @jessag: I personally wouldn't do that since bold is sign of importance or emphasis and thus has different purpose.

Comment: I can't accept "consistence within the post" as a valid answer. Of course that's important, but it could still look hideous, and what about consistence across the **site**? For me, it would make more sense if people posted all the reasonable options as answers to be voted on, and the top 1 or 2 voted answers becomes the standard.

Comment: I prefer code spans since actually, _this is not italics_ but emphasized text (check the HTML source).

Comment: @Dukeling: I feel that no standard should be given for this because the use cases vary so heavily. For example, lets assume the inline code formatting was the standard for file names. Now, I am writing a lot of inline code blocks withing my post and need to include one file name in between of them. It wouldn't stand out at all and would mix to the code blocks. Lets take another example where the standard forces italics to be used instead. This time I'm writing a lot of library/programming language/product names in my answer and want to emphasis them with the italics. Same problem occurs.

Answer (score 17):

At first sight, using `code` format is appealing. A file name may be thought of as being somewhat similar to code. As [@LightnessRacesinOrbit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) so appropriately puts it in a [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303145/how-should-files-names-be-formatted#comment237767_303228), a file is a "thing that is quoted verbatim from a computer terminal", and thus it (more or less) qualifies as code. Still, in certain cases it may be desirable to have a format to distinguish file names from (the rest of the) code.

Another possibility is to use *italic* or **bold**. That way the file name is distinguished from actual code. But italic or bold are often used for emphasis. It would be best not to confuse a file name with an emphasized word or phrase.

Taking this into account, a good solution may be to use *`italic code`* or **`bold code`** format for file names. That way the filename looks similar to code, but there's a distinction. (And of course it should be used consistently thoughout the post, as mentioned by [sanfor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303147/2586922).)

Comment: The fact that a filename is not a function or a variable is a non sequitur. Things which are not functions or variables can appropriately have code formatting.

Comment: @jwg You are right. What I meant is that a filename is not exactly code. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @LuisMendo: No but it does fit the bill as a "thing that is quoted verbatim from a computer terminal" which I count as valid for code formatting. e.g. shell prompt, compilation command, output of `-v`, etc.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks. That's the idea I was struggling to convey when I said "being somewhat similar to code, like a variable or function name". I've edited my answer to incorporate this

Comment: Italic is all you need. The rest is too shouty, especially the fugly monospace.

Comment: @tchrist But italic is also used for other purposes too, so it may be confusing. Besides, monospace is often associated with "things that are quoted verbatim from a computer terminal", such as a file. Is it "fugly"? That depends on personal taste :-)

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes file names are specific commands to be run, and in that instance I think code formatting is most appropriate: `netsh.exe show mode`.

Comment: +1: If it is a fixed name that the user should type exactly as shown, use code formatting.  If it is a placeholder or example file name that the user can or should replace then italic is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

There are different options:

- plugin.yml
- *plugin.yml*
- **plugin.yml**
- ***plugin.yml***
- `plugin.yml`
- *`plugin.yml`*
- **`plugin.yml`**
- ***`plugin.yml`***
- <kbd>plugin.yml</kbd>
- *<kbd>plugin.yml</kbd>*
- **<kbd>plugin.yml</kbd>**
- ***<kbd>plugin.yml</kbd>***

Personally, I use italic formatting.

- *plugin.yml*

Comment: If you want to enumerate them...  Abuse of intended usage:  <kbd>plugin.yml</kbd> (which is fully nestable with all the others.  I actually rather like how <kbd>*plugin.yml*</kbd> looks, now that I've seen it)

Comment: @Izkata Added more options.

Comment: Anything but the first two sucks, because the rest of them mangle the page color. They should be reserved for ransom notes.

Comment: using `<kbd>` tag in markup is *not* appropriate for a filename, in general. "The <kbd> HTML element represents a span of inline text denoting textual user input from a keyboard, voice input, or any other text entry device." per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd

Comment: For one *specific* use, it might be semantically ok to use the `<kbd>` tag: when the document is directing a user to *type* a filename. Generally speaking, this is not how filenames are used in documentation.

Comment: @tchrist I personally appreciate the humor; however, your rationale above uses appearance (e.g. page color, a 'presentation' issue) as a justification. It is better to choose markup based on *semantics*. One reference: https://marcomm.nd.edu/blog/always-use-semantic-markup/

Answer (score 2):

At least with code, we use file names—verbally and in writing—almost like the *title* of the contents within the files.

For a creative work, such as a novel or a film, we italicize the title of the work. Although I'll never write a piece of code as magnificent as *The Lord of the Rings*, I don't think it's too much of a stretch to consider code as a type of composition and to suggest that we use italics when citing the "titles":

- "The server seems stuck in an infinite loop at *RingCollectionSingleton.java*, line 1."
- "How can I decouple my code from *DisposableOrcFactory.cs*?"
- "Whoops! I forgot to check in changes to *DarkLord.php* yesterday..."
- "I need help debugging my *wizardry.sh*. It's keeping our tests from passing."

As illustrated above, italics provide a reasonable distinction for file names, at least visually. For those of us resolutely concerned about the semantics of markup generated, we can use `<i>…</i>` tags in place of markdown to avoid designating titles as *emphasis*.

Speaking of semantics, `inline code formatting` seems like fair option, but I think we can distinguish between *referring to a file* ("here's my *.htaccess*") and describing a file name *used in code or a command* ("check that `somefile.csv` exists in that function") by marking the former with italics and the latter as code.

Answer (score -5):

In my opinion, all code related things should be used in `code blocks`, thus being more pleasant for the viewer. But it doesn't have a formal way to do that.