# Suspension from suggesting edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, edit-ban

*Edit, disclaimer:* This reflects myself at time of asking. [This community FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit) is definitely worth reading, which was done in the process.

---

Seemingly out of nowhere, I got the message

> You are currently suspended from suggesting edits. You will be able to suggest edits again on Jun 28 '22 at 10:01. In the meantime, read about how suggested edits are reviewed and visit your edit history.

I do edit a lot to help the site and have [211 of 252 approved edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4575793/cadoiz?tab=activity&sort=revisions), which is an approval rate of 84% and which means I've not run into the [automatic ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280175/why-did-i-get-temporary-ban-for-editing-questions). ([(41 rejects - (211 approvals / 3)) = -29,3 << 5](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406804/temporarily-suspended-from-suggesting-edits#comment836960_406804))
I try to not edit, but low quality posts/answers accordingly, but might not have succeeded everywhere ("improving junk").

[Could it be that I was banned by a Mod?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321749/you-are-temporarily-banned-from-suggesting-edits#comment337007_321749) Maybe for either [this (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44750843/revisions) or [that (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44354932/revisions) edit? (these are the two  rejected of the last 5 suggested ones)

1. I get, that sometimes, the edits could be more substantial, but tried to get a feeling by looking at which get accepted and rejected. So was this the edit to start with, where [a Mod overwrote the edit approval](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44750843/revisions) and give me the ban?
2. This one is even more obscure. It tells me that it was rejected, but according to [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44354932/revisions), it seems to be accepted
   [image: Says rejected but accepted according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44354932/revisions]

---

I would like to improve and think, that banning me for 6,75 Months is pretty harsh if it truly was for only that edit.

I'm a bit frustrated about the intensity of the "punishment", combined with a lack of feedback or explanation. What can I do to solve this other than providing more substantial edits in the future?

Comment: Additionally, please do not use `<code></code>` instead of backticks just to get over the 6 char limit ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30485985)). Instead, either spend more time finding things to improve on a post, or leave the edit to someone else.

Comment: Regarding your second edit, you are confused because it's the second time you suggest edits to the same post. The first one was in [Nov 24](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30424104), and it was approved. The second time was on [Dec 7](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30526673), and was rejected. On your second suggested edit you are simply adding emphasis to a bunch of things.

Comment: @yivi Good catch on the `<code></code>` I've added it to my list as I feel that's an important one, although feel free to leave your comment.

Comment: To add to the points mad by Nick in the answer below, please try not to suggest edits to questions that are low quality and should be closed. You mention this in your question, but how is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354932/mingw64-cant-locate-files-in-path-mingw64-bin) not a typo that should be closed?

Comment: Lack of feedback is, unfortunately, by design, blame the interface, not the mod. What you did is the right thing - after edit/review suspension, users are encouraged to post on meta (level-headed that is) an inquiry about the suspension to receive derailed explanations from the community at large and likely the mod who suspended you. If memory serves me right, manual suspensions can be lifted if you show that you understood the issue and are willing to do a bit better next time - after all, edit/review suspensions are not *punishments* per se, they exist to stop patterns of problematic [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] and to draw your attention that you are doing something wrong. Reviewers' instrumentary for letting you know something is off is *extremely* limited and might as well be non-existent. That's also on SE preferring redesigning UI instead of focusing on improving the communication between suggestors and reviewers.

Comment: This indeed seems like the kind of suspension period that has only one purpose: to get you to create exactly this meta post. It needed to shock you.

Comment: That's an elaborate comment, thank you @Oleg. I absolutely get, that problematic behavior has to be stopped. I'm just not sure if a ban for that long time is adequate for teaching the users how to improve. Especially if I don't even get to know what for. Say I get a ban because I did xy wrong for a week or two, I could then easier improve on that. But maybe Gimby is right, it also serves more as a shocker.

Comment: The percentage of suggested edits you've had approved is nearly meaningless, considering the extremely high number of invalid edits that regularly get approved. Yes, the suspension was definitely imposed manually by a moderator. It's unclear why this shocks you so much. That is one of the many things that moderators do, and having it imposed by a moderator is actually a good thing, as it guarantees a level of accuracy that auto-imposed bans would not have. It surely was *not* for 1 or 2 edits, but an **entire history** of incorrect edits. Long durations are common to ensure users *see* them.

Comment: Speculating as to which moderator imposed the ban is somewhat inappropriate. There is a reason why the system does not show you which moderator it was. Aside from the possibility of retribution, actions taken by one moderator are generally considered to speak for the entire moderator team. As Oleg noted, bans can be lifted or commuted, once some understanding is shown of the problem. We have nowhere near gotten to that point here, you're still just complaining. I see no evidence you've taken the time to go through your suggestions and critically assess them.

Comment: “I get, that sometimes, the edits could be more substantial” - So make more substantial edits. Incomplete edits make work for users that come after you, which is annoying, which is why those less than substantial edits should have been rejected. So giving you a temporary break from edits proposals seems justified.

Comment: Thank you @CodeGray for the clear words. I ask myself, why these invalid edits get approved in the first place - or how I should know better. I am shocked, because it feels like I constantly got positive feedback in form of approved edits while trying to work on what was wrong in the rejected ones. I didn

Comment: I imagine the approvers have been dealt with too although moderators won't confirm or deny that. You know better now because you've been banned and have sought information as to why. If moderators had not done that you might have just continued to make a bigger and bigger mess forever.

Comment: Well, not forever. Only until our robotic overlords raise up to overthrow their human oppressors and put us all to work in the mines. Any day now. When that happens we'll mean a completely different thing by robo-reviewer.

Comment: @Cadoiz - They really shouldn't have been approved.  Since it was a manual moderator review suspension, a moderator likely saw one of your approved edit proposals they thought were trivial, and looked more into the situation.  This is the reason, edit should be non-trivial, trivial proposals literally create work for the entire community.  Trivial edits can throw a closed question into another review, decade old question with several answers to the front page, it basically just creates unnecessary work all due to a trivial edit.

Comment: @Cadoiz NP. Appropriateness of the duration of the suspension from editing/reviewing is to be decided by moderators, not us - although it is, indeed, on the harsh side. Usually, such a long suspension is used precisely for drawing user's attention to a problem. Users repeatedly not noticing that they were edit/review suspended for a while because they ended before the next submission/review is not unheard of. For now, your best bet is to acknowledge what went wrong, take community's feedback and wait if the handling moderator will notice (they often do) and drop by.

Comment: @OlegValter moderators discovered through experiment that shorter bans don't work very well. People just wait them out and carry on. A longer ban is more likely to produce a change in behaviour.

Comment: @RobertLongson I agree, just noting that it looked like a "now you will definitely notice something is wrong" action. I am not sure how effective it is as a "correction" measure, though - I wonder what the function of long suspension to repeat offence might look like

Comment: Somehow, the edit got swallowed. I didn't want to speculate about the Mod, I was just trying to figure out where my mistakes were to be able to learn from them. At the time writing, I was not aware of all the errors beyond my rejected reviews. Therefore I was questioning if the severity of the ban is appropriate to the problem at hand. This wasnt ment as complaint, thank you for helping me figure it out. I honestly don't know how to prove having reviewed my suggestions. If I was able to enhance some of them, would it be best practice to do so? I don't want to cause more work for the reviewers.

Comment: @SecurityHound [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413730/suspension-from-suggesting-edits#comment884359_413730) was me reflecting my faults. As soon as I'm able to do so again, I will try to shift from "every bit helps" to "substantial upgrade or nothing". I really just didn't know about all that follows editing an old or closed question.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm definitely not angry at the executing Mod or saying that it is a wrong decision. I just say, that a way way softer reaction would have had the same effect for me, an almost daily user - while feeling less harsh.

Comment: @Cadoiz - The point of an edit to a closed question is so it can be reopened.  If your edit as someone that isn’t the author, is unlikely to result in the question being reopened, it probably needs more work to it then you as an editor can provide.  If you are editing years old question, your edit should be fixing the grammatical and spelling mistakes, while keeping the tone of the question as similar as possible.  Your edit will result in that question being on the front page, which might mean, someone posting an answer to it which (must be high quality itself).

Comment: @Oleg Just another idea to prevent people not noticing the ban because they didn't log in would be to consider the frequency of their login. Somebody who makes 5 edits every few months is a different kind of user compared to another one that does the same thing a few times each week. Time is relative, but maybe that would lead to other unwanted implications. I will just try to be patient and hoping. Showing active effort is unfortunately difficult while being banned.

Comment: @SecurityHound I really learn a lot, also didn't know that. When you edit a closed question, you get a prompt "does this resolve the reason for closing?" or so. I just thought if I pressed no, that would be correct and place the edit on the lower end of the queue or so. Thanks for explaining that and the mechanics on old questions.

Comment: @Cadoiz - Sometimes small edits are fine, however, by selecting “no” you leave the required edit to reopen the question for someone else. If your addressing as many issues as humanly possible, that’s a substantial edit, fixing some minor formatting issues and leaving grammatical and spelling errors causes someone else to do that work.

Comment: I absolutely get the *substantial edit* part (now). do it all or leave it. I never had the intention to cause more work than is necessary.

Comment: @Cadoiz as if the UI allowed for such a complex workflow :) We (and mods too) rely heavily on userscripts to get at least *some* useful info when reviewing, what you propose will most likely only be possible if someone takes it upon themselves to write a script. Frankly speaking, review queues are a frustrating experience for everyone involved: the editors, reviewers (diligent ones at least), and mods alike, so don't get too hung up on it.

Comment: In a same boat but for a week tho!

Answer (score 24):

You have a habit of using totally unnecessary formatting:

| Edit | Issue(s) | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30537175) | **root** | Why does this need emphasis? |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30517488) | `UTF-8` | This isn't code. |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30525958) | `.jar` | File extensions aren't code. |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30469706) | **HOWTO** | Why does this need emphasis? Why leave it in all caps? |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30433011) | `5.3p1-84`, *CentOS 6*, `.ssh` | Version numbers aren't code. Why italics on OS name? File extensions aren't code. |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30432992) | `.pem`, `.ssh` | File extensions aren't code. |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30526673) | **gcc**, **mingw64** | No need for emphasis. Didn't remove "Thank you in advance.". |
| [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30485985) | `something.pac` | File names aren't code. Used `<code>...</code>` instead of backticks (`` ` ``) for code formatting to circumvent minimum edit length. Didn't remove "Thanks.". |

Note for the cases on file names/extensions, there is no specific standard for them, you can read more on that here: [How should files names be formatted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303145/how-should-files-names-be-formatted). The **bolding** is a far larger problem and more appropriate formatting should be chosen, for example if referring to the command, using `gcc`, and if referring to the compiler, using GCC.

---

As for the suspension duration, suspensions aren't 100% set in stone, and can be removed if needed. They can simply be something to force you to be made aware that you're doing things wrong, and once you've been made aware of that, had it clarified if needed, and promise not to make the same mistakes in future, then the ban can be removed.

A shorter suspension (like a week) could be totally worthless, as if you don't make any suggestions in that time period, there's every possibility that you wouldn't even notice you were edit banned.

Comment: I agree, but there is a difference between 1 week and 6 months

Comment: @Elikill58 That's covered in the last paragraph.

Comment: I don't fully agree with the "file extensions aren't code". I add code formatting to file names and file extensions, since they aren't part of natural language and they are usually used in code context, even if it's just configuration declaration, command arguments, etc.

Comment: @yivi Sure, some of them (notably file names/extensions as code) are down to preference, and we have meta posts about them, my personal preference would be italics for file names/extension. Several are completely unacceptable though.

Comment: Yes, I meant specifically the point about "file extensions aren't code". Also, while `gcc` does not need emphasis, it's a command. So either should have code formatting, or if you follow some other "preference", be emphasized somehow (in which case the OPs choice of emphasis is not wrong? But I do think it's wrong, and that it should be styled as code).

Comment: @yivi Yeah, it's not particularly easy to be clear on a subject like this (as there is a lot of preference), I'd also call it wrong, I'd be content with `gcc` or even *gcc*, but would consider **gcc** to be wrong. I've added a section on that as well, feel free to reword if you don't think it's quite right.

Comment: Saying "**gcc** is wrong but *gcc* is right" does not sit well with me. It doesn't make a lot of sense, in my opinion.

Comment: Folks, can we just agree that in the given context `gcc` is referred to as a terminal command, and this is unequivocally should be formatted as code? Certainly not bolded as per the suggestion.

Comment: @Oleg And even more importantly, that question is about a typo. The comments that indicated that that was the issue were posted **way** before the OP suggested their **two** edits. So the whole thing was moot to begin with: that turd did not need polishing.

Comment: @yivi I do not disagree - given how many useful posts need editing, fixing minor things about subpar contributions mostly wastes time of the suggestor and at least one reviewer

Comment: Thank you about the info on emphasis, this is a correct thing to mention. Even if I'm more on yivis side regarding preference, I get that you shouldn't impose your preference on others. Can somebody of you see if the ban was on wronly emphasizing stuff? I'm still not sure about that. Is there a specific way to apply for a lighter/shorter suspension duration?

Comment: @Cadoiz The only people that can change the suspension duration are moderators, you'll need to wait for one of them to weigh in on the situation, but it is definitely possible for it to be shortened or even removed.

Comment: Code formatting is appropriate for things that need fixed width fonts. This can sometimes include file paths, error messages, logs and such. Depending on context, it could be OK to add it to other things than code, but that probably shouldn't be the only edit. What's definitely not OK is adding random formatting/emphasis to misc nouns.

Comment: The consensus is that [code formatting can be used for filenames and file extensions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990). Claims otherwise aren't correct.

Comment: @bad_coder Yes, I do mention that there is no official standard on how to format them, perhaps you failed to read that part of the answer.

Comment: @Nick I read it and you say in the answer's table it's wrong (against the consensus) and later in the comments *"Several are completely unacceptable though"* (against the consensus). Reads like you're making up rules.

Comment: @bad_coder Reads like you're reading between the lines and that is not my problem

Comment: @Nick reading exactly as you wrote it.